# Expo EAS local build: Cannot find module '@expo/config-plugins'

Tags: expo

With eas-cli version 0.52.0, the local build generates the apk as expected.

When using eas-cli version >= 0.53.0 I get the following error: `Cannot find module '@expo/config-plugins'`.

I use the following command as I always did: `eas build --profile preview --platform android --local`.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue using `"expo": "^41.0.0"`

I already install `npx expo install expo-build-properties` and it turns out the version of expo-build-properties is 0.4.1 so I think this version isn't compatible with either the expo version or other packages version so I tried to downgrade the version by editing `package.json`

so changing from

`"expo-build-properties": "^0.4.1",`

to

`"expo-build-properties": "^0.3.0",`

and run `yarn install` / `npm install`

Now the build run successful.

Answer (score 2):

If you using "expo-build-properties" in your app.json/app.config.js/app.configInstall the package with `npx expo install expo-build-properties` to ensure you are using the correct version for your expo sdk.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem I have resolved with this command

npx expo install expo-screen-orientation

issue was in versioning npx expo automatically downgraded my version of expo-screen-orientation

from version 5.0.1 to 4.0.3, after that the error was gone

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and after wasting a lot of time searching for the solution, I managed to know what was happening.

The module "expo/config-plugins" was installed but npm and expo couldn't find it at all.

I managed to find the issue by removing the plugin one by one from the file app.json (which should be at the same level with package.json).
Every time I removed one plugin from the file, I tried again to run a command (either **expo start** or **expo doctor** for example) and then I managed to find the plugin that caused the issue. Once found, I did another **npm install** and then added back the plugin in the app.json file.

After that the error disappeared.